# Download pdf instead of opening into new tab in Chrome from excel vba via Selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download pdf files from an excel macro with selenium webdriver. The pdf is being opened in  a new tab and I could not figure out how to download directly instead. I toggeled on pdf download setting in chrome and working fine when doing it manually. However, via automation that setting is toggeled off by default.

How can we turn that setting on to direct download in chrome instance created by selenium webdriver?

```
    Sub Invoice_Download()

    Dim Obj As New WebDriver
    Dim L As Long

    Obj.Start "chrome", ""
    Obj.Get "https://companyportal.com/login/"
    Obj.FindElementById("user_email").SendKeys ("username")
    Obj.FindElementById("user_password").SendKeys ("password")
    Obj.FindElementById("submit_button").Click

    L = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A1").Select
    For rowNo = 2 To L
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        'Clear existing number from search box
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").Clear
            'Enter a new invoice number saved in the macors workbook.
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("A" & rowNo).Value)
            'Click on searh button
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]").Click
        'Click on the found invoice link
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]").Click
        'Click on download button
        Obj.FindElementByLinkText("Download PDF").Click
    Next 'Proceed to next invoice number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution. Posting as answer. adding this line fixed the problem. `Obj.SetPreference "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", True`

```
    Sub Invoice_Download()

    Dim Obj As New WebDriver
    Dim L As Long

    Obj.SetPreference "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", True
    Obj.Start "chrome", ""
    Obj.Get "https://companyportal.com/login/"
    Obj.FindElementById("user_email").SendKeys ("username")
    Obj.FindElementById("user_password").SendKeys ("password")
    Obj.FindElementById("submit_button").Click

    L = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A1").Select
    For rowNo = 2 To L
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        'Clear existing number from search box
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").Clear
            'Enter a new invoice number saved in the macors workbook.
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("A" & rowNo).Value)
            'Click on searh button
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]").Click
        'Click on the found invoice link
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]").Click
        'Click on download button
        Obj.FindElementByLinkText("Download PDF").Click
    Next 'Proceed to next invoice number
End Sub
```